# 'main.cpp:1: No include path in which to find iostream'

Tags: c++, gcc

I just tried to compile simple Hello World in C++ using MinGW compiler in my Windows 10 command line. I used the command `gcc main.cpp`, and as I hit enter, I got this error: 'main.cpp:1: No include path in which to find iostream'.
What is the error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Use `g++ main.cpp`

The command `gcc` is setup for c compilation. It does not link the c++ standard library.
`g++` does link c++ standard library.

Comment: But the error the OP is getting is not a linker error.

Comment: hmm, true. I answered a bit too fast there.